# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Media Queries Reversed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been experiencing an odd and really frustrating problem with certain page elements (use h1.brand different em sizes are being ignored as one example) that won't down size at responsive break points and even increase in size despite modified CSS using traditional Media Queries. When using Google Chrome developer tools it will show these elements as following the opposite or at least incorrect media query for a given screen size.

Help, I've searched and tried many different fixes with no luck,

Thanks for any help,

TVprodDude

Site is Live at tvadpros.com

Below is a couple of the media queries – placed at top of master css stylesheet - Maybe I have something wrong here:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
.container {
    width: 440px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto; 
}

h1.brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

}

/* Small Devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.container {
    width: 720px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto; 
}
.column {
    /* float: left; */
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

h1.brand {
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/* .row {
    overflow: hidden;
}  */

ul.sdt_menu {
    /*margin-left:500px; */
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    width: 640px;
}
ul.sdt_menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
ul.sdt_menu li{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:45px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.sdt_menu li > a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:45px;
    z-index:12;
    background:transparent url(../images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li a img{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:45px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:45px;
    z-index:15;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active{
    position:absolute;
    background:#111;
    top:45px;
    width:100px;
    height:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:14;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr{
    color:#f5f5f5;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:95px; /*For dumbass IE7*/
    font-size: 9px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:140px;
    top:65px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:#000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    line-height:25px;
    color:#0B75AF;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:first-child{
    margin-top: 9px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
/* img.size-chg {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px; */
}
/* End nav menu for min 768px width */
```

/* Medium Devices, Desktops, 992px and up */
@media (min-width: 992px)

Comment: Everything seems to work as expected with your code Greater than 768px = 3em, 767px to 480px = 2em. I think you will need to provide more detail for what you are expecting to happen at each break point, and what you are seeing happen at each breakpoint.

Comment: When I look at your live site I see the error. You have unbalanced `}`. The culprit is, most likely, line 168 in your grid.css.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, Just checked the closing bracket you mentioned, but that closes the 768 min media query on stylesheet. On grid.css (which I have unlinked from html pages currently) it closes the 992 min query.

Comment: Your live site also does not have your "480px" media query closed.

Comment: And your "992px" media query is using max-width, not min-width.

Comment: Ahh, yes on live site that could be, I haven't uploaded modified pages. Thanks

Comment: OK, stylesheets changed. As for details on h1.brand "TVADPROS" at upper left it stays at 2em as screen size is increased (same with nav menu) despite modified CSS at media queries for them to increase in size. Than at 480px page break and below the h1.brand jumps to full 4 em and nav menu suddenly jumps up in size?? It's been baffling me for days.

Comment: Ok, now both stay at larger size, even at 480px and below page break?